# How to set bash path for both java and python

Tags: java, python, bash, macos

I have just installed OpenJDK8 latest version in and changed my default java_home and version in bash, but why the system still shows that I am in openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"? I don't even know when I installed the 1.8.0_152-release version.

```
Yilins-Macbook-Pro:~$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.0_232, x86_64:  "AdoptOpenJDK 8"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
Yilins-Macbook-Pro:~$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
Yilins-Macbook-Pro:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b12, mixed mode)
```

**Update:** OK here is the problem. My original path is set to anaconda thus the java version is the one under anaconda.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# export PATH="/Users/liyilin/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

But here is another issue regarding path. If I changed the path for JAVA_HOME, my original path for python is no longer useful. Is there a way to make them both exists when operating? Otherwise I need to keep changing back and forth when writing java and python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put both things in your path

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export ANACONDA_HOME="/Users/liyilin/anaconda3" 

export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${ANACONDA_HOME}/bin:$PATH"
```

Also, I would suggest using SDKman for Java things and pyenv for python... Both will update your PATH for you and allow you to easily upgrade versions. For example, you should switch to at least Java 11

Homebrew is another option

Answer (score 0):

Run `source .bash_profile` to take the changes on .bash_profile to take effect.

Comment: set in this order - python path, java home then path with java home. I think the last java will survive in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the previous version or remove the previous version path from environmental path .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).